# Keycloak returns 403 code after authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, keycloak

I have keycloak and another spring boot application in docker compose.

Keycloak and my application both start and run correctly. I added a realm, client and a role using keycloak admin console. Then I assigned the role to the user.

I tried to access my application's endpoint which is protected by keycloak, and after providing the correct credentials in the keycloak login pop-up, I see 403 - forbidden status in F12 network tab.

docker-compose keycloak part:

```
  keycloak:
    restart: on-failure
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:12.0.4
    container_name: keycloak
    networks:
      - network1
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: user
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: password
      WAIT_HOSTS: mysql:3306
      TZ: Europe/Zagreb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

application.properties:

```
#Client registration
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=test2
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid

#OIDC provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/test
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.authorization-uri=http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri=http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

SecurityConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

    SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {
        this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .hasRole("test");
                http.csrf().disable();
        http.oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

In *hosts* file on path *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts* i added this alias:`127.0.0.1 keycloak`.
I did this because of communication problems between my app and keycloak in docker containers.

Endpoints which are not protected by keycloak can be accessed without problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the value of issuer uri on the openid configuration endpoint? `http://keycloakhost:keycloakport/auth/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Comment: @birca123 this is part of the response:
```"issuer": "http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/test"```